# Prevent HTTP connection from staying open for slow servers

Tags: java, http, server, tcp

I need to set a hard limit on how long my application will wait for a response from a server. Read timeout doesn't accomplish this because it's a timeout for when the last data was sent. Servers that send just a little bit data frequently have taken 1-5 seconds to load files.

```java
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.setConnectTimeout(300); // Max amount of time to establish a connection
conn.setReadTimeout(700); // Max amount of time between data

Reader responseReader = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
char[] buffer = new char[1024];
StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();

// Loop until 0 characters are read
for(int numRead; (numRead = responseReader.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
    body.append(buffer, 0, numRead); // Append any chars that were read. Use "numRead" to only add characters read from the input stream
}

return body.toString();
```

I tried creating a variable which tracked the start time of reading the body, then compared the current time to it upon receiving any data. While this worked in preventing the program from reading the request body for a long time, it did nothing for the headers. It also seems clunky.